# Get list item when its null or undefined

Tags: javascript, custom-list, hyperlink

So I have this code

```
while (listItemEnumeratorlistReady.moveNext()) {
        footerListItem = listItemEnumeratorlistReady.get_current();
        arTitle.push(footerListItem.get_item('Title'));
        arDescription.push(footerListItem.get_item('PublishingPageContent'));

        arUrlLink.push(footerListItem.get_item('Link').get_url());
        arUrlTitle.push(footerListItem.get_item('Link').get_description());
        }
```

Which is getting elements back from a list, sometimes the Link column (which is a hyperlink type) wont get filled in. However when I try and bring it back its throwing an error:

> unable to get property get_url of undefined or null reference.

Is ther anyway to make it ignore the item if this column is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CAML to get rid of null values.

```
<IsNotNull>  
    <FieldRef Name='Link' />   
</IsNotNull>
```

If you use it null values will not be included in the results.

OR check for `null` value in your code.

```
if (footerListItem.get_item('Link')) {
    arUrlLink.push(footerListItem.get_item('Link').get_url());
    arUrlTitle.push(footerListItem.get_item('Link').get_description());
}
```

Comment: but I want to show the other columns for the ones that are null as well

Comment: Answer updated ..

Comment: What happen?? Solved your issue @jimmy2holes

Comment: If the field isn't required, you are going to have to do your own null checking in the code like Atish notes, or the script will blow up, and that goes for all non-required fields you are going to reference.

Comment: sorry went away and have just seen this, i'll try now